# Ensuring that an array is an array of floats

Tags: python

What is the syntax to ensure that the array self.project_marks is an array of floats?

```
MAX_PROJECTS = 17

class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_id, first_name, last_name, pronoun, discipline, grade=0.0):
        # Run validation on the received arguments
        # assert student_id >= 0, f"Student ID must be greater than or equal to zero!"

        self.student_id = student_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.pronoun = pronoun  # he she
        self.discipline = discipline
        self.grade = grade  # 0 to 100
        self.project_marks = [0] * MAX_PROJECTS

    def get_total_marks(self):
        return sum(self.project_marks)

    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade
```

Do I make MAX_PROJECTS = 17.0 or what?

Comment: You should edit your question to say what language this is.

Comment: You can use a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). You can also explicitly check the type of the contained items if you didn't trust the data source, but how careful you are in that regard just depends on who's using the code and what they are using it for. But you are not initializing it with floats. It should be `[0.0] * 17`. Not the other way around. The `17` has to be an integer, since it's the size of the list. You can't have a list size be a floating point value.

Comment: `self.project_marks` is not an array, it is a list. It really isn't clear what you are trying to achieve. Currently, you created a list with only `int` objects, because `0` is an `int` object. but that is almost certainly fine since `int` objects work well with `float` objects.  You could use `0.0`, which woudl be a `float`, **but why does it matter**? Can you please elaborate on *exactly what you are trying to accomplish*?

Comment: As an aside, stop writing getters in Python. It is pointless and unidiomatic.

Comment: The paradigm in Python would be to use type hints, and if a user of the module puts a datatype into the list that causes a method referencing the list to later throw an exception, then that's on the user.  As Guido puts it ,"we're all adults here".  It would be possible to somewhat enforce this with properties and using methods to do type checking before updating the list, but as there are no private attributes/variables you can't completely stop someone from bypassing those setters/getters.

Comment: "Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to accomplish?" I need to be able to give a student 3.25 as a mark on a project.  That looks like a float to me... Therefore I wanted to ensure that it was a float.  Oh, and the getters are left over from my C++ code and are not in the current Python version.  I left them in to show how self.project_marks are used.

Comment: Generally, you don't worry about it. `int` and `float` is a distinction mostly hidden from the user, and both will just magically work with arithmetic operators (as of Python 3, float division and integer division are separate operators as well, so there's no risk of integer values accidentally truncating your quotient). So all of this is to say, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `MAX_PROJECT` to `float` actually won't work, because the multiplication operator expects an integer when it's applied to a `list`.

Instead you should change the `list` that you're trying to repeat to contain values of type `float`:

```
self.project_marks = [0.0] * MAX_PROJECTS
print(self.project_marks)
```

prints:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: But why? What would be the purpose here? Also, that is not an array, that is a `list`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know why OP wants it, but that's what they were asking. And python's `list` is better known in CS circles as an array.

Comment: @YakovGalka If someone else uses the wrong term, that is no reason for us to do the same. A `list` and an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) are different things in Python.

Comment: @Matthias at no point I referred to the python's `array` type -- notice the formatting. As far as terminology goes, python is the one who got it wrong. Its so called `list`, being a random access data structure, is what most people call an array. The word "list" usually presumes sequential non-random access data structure, i.e. a linked list of some sort. And `array` would probably be better called a `vector`.

Comment: Sorry, List it is.  I am revisiting Python from some time spent in C++ and I apologize for misspeaking.  [] to me says array in my head when it should say list.